# Are pre-trained models vor CIFAR-10 / CIFAR-100 / SVHN available?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I know that there are various pre-trained models available for ImageNet (e.g. [VGG 16](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/vgg16.py), [Inception v3](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/inception_v3.py), [Resnet 50](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/resnet50.py), [Xception](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/xception.py)). Is there something similar for the tiny datasets (CIFAR-10, CIFAR-100, SVHN)?

Comment: Pretrained VGG model: https://gist.github.com/baraldilorenzo/07d7802847aaad0a35d3

Answer (score 1):

Yes, google the various "Model Zoo" (e.g. one for caffe here: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Model-Zoo), they host a bunch of models including  "tiny" ones.

Comment: I just found https://www.gradientzoo.com/ - interesting!